# How to access report data in a "App + Web" google analytics property using The Google Analytics Reporting API v4?

Tags: google-analytics-api

I have a Web+App google analytics property, and I need to access report data using The Google Analytics Reporting API v4. In the docs, the field viewId is required to build a ReportRequest object. But, in the new google analytics Web+App feature, you cannot create a view from the property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For GA4 Properties, you need to use the Google Analytics Data API v1. See the devsite: https://developers.google.com/analytics/trusted-testing/analytics-data

App + Web Properties were recently renamed to GA4 Properties. See the blog post: https://blog.google/products/marketingplatform/analytics/new_google_analytics/.

The Google Analytics Reporting API v4 (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4) accepts numeric view identifiers in report requests. GA4 Properties do not have views, and there is not a way to create views in those properties.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Reporting API v4 doesn't support App+Web properties for the exact reason you stated - the API only understands view ID's and not property ID's.

Looking at the documentation, it's noted there that it doesn't support your setup, however, they do have a tester program that allows you to test and provide feedback when it comes to new reporting features for properties like the one you use.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4